How to list the excluded packages in some repository?
We have 3 repositories in the CentOS 7.6.1810 system, the repository of centos has one excluded package.
And then we used the following methods to find the unknown excluded package, but they all just failed
yum -d9 list|grep  exclude
yum -d9 search all exclude|grep exclude
yum -d9 install <some package>|grep exclude
yum -d9 check-update|grep exclude

# yum -v repolist
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "langpacks" plugin
Adding en_US.UTF-8 to language list
Adding zh_CN.UTF-8 to language list
Config time: 0.013
Yum version: 3.4.3
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.019
Repo-id      : centos
Repo-name    : centos
Repo-revision: 1562756941
Repo-updated : Wed Jul 10 19:12:01 2019
Repo-pkgs    : 30,008
Repo-size    : 46 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///app/centos7.6/
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Tue Jul 15 18:54:09 2024)
  Filter     : read-only:present
Repo-excluded: 1
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo

Repo-id      : epel
Repo-name    : epel
Repo-revision: 1561335207
Repo-updated : Mon Jun 24 08:22:39 2019
Repo-pkgs    : 13,237
Repo-size    : 15 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///app/epel/
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Tue Jul 15 18:54:09 2024)
  Filter     : read-only:present
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo

Repo-id      : zabbix
Repo-name    : zabbix
Repo-revision: 1543310530
Repo-updated : Tue Nov 27 17:22:11 2018
Repo-pkgs    : 41
Repo-size    : 32 M
Repo-baseurl : http://172.25.191.5/app/zabbixyum/yum/
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Tue Jul 15 18:54:09 2024)
  Filter     : read-only:present
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/zabbix.repo

repolist: 43,286

